# Enable Open Shading Language in Python

Tags: python, osl

I have a script that I run to automate a task from CLI using `blender --background --python my_automation_script.py` which has a material with a `ShaderNodeScript` node.

That script ensures that cycles is the render engine with `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'` but I cannot find a way to enable Open Shading Language in a similar way.

Is it possible to enable Open Shading Language from a Python script? Or alternatively, from the CLI call to blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the 'Scripting' tab in recent Blender versions and toggle the Open Shading Language checkbox you can see the property name that is being affected by that change :

```
bpy.context.scene.cycles.shading_system = True
```

Set the property to True to enable OSL or to False to disable OSL.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly. I didn't actually know you could do that with the scripting tab. That's super helpful.